# How to use react-select-async-paginate library on change of different select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to implement 2 select box
1st select box will be the simple select box.
2nd select box will have infinite scroller functionality and for this, I am using the **[react-select-async-paginate](https://github.com/vtaits/react-select-async-paginate/tree/master/packages/react-select-async-paginate)** library.

**Issue Explanation**

AsyncPaginate is the component of react-select-async-paginate library. It uses loadOptions function attribute to load the option into the select box and it expect return value as {options: [], hasMore: false}.

In my code, in the loadOptions attribute, I am calling the loadHostOptions function to get the options. And on change of the first dropdown, I am calling loadHostOptions function. But in this case, correct options are not reflected in the 2nd dropdown.

Can anyone help me with how to load options on the change of the first dropdown?

[Here is codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-example-forked-d21yys)

**Code**

```
import React from "react";

import { AsyncPaginate } from "react-select-async-paginate";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstSelectVal: "",
      value: null
    };
  }

  firstSelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ firstSelectVal: event.target.value });
    if (event.target.value) {
      this.loadHostOptions("java", []);
    }
  };

  onPagiChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event});
  };

  loadHostOptions = async (search, prevOptions) => {
    if (search === "java") {
      const responseJSON = {
        results: [
          {
            value: 1,
            label: "Java"
          }
        ],
        has_more: false
      };

      return {
        options: responseJSON.results,
        hasMore: responseJSON.has_more
      };
    } else {
      const responseJSON = {
        results: [
          {
            value: 1,
            label: "Java"
          },
          {
            value: 2,
            label: "C++"
          },
          {
            value: 3,
            label: "Python"
          },
          {
            value: 4,
            label: "Node"
          },
          {
            value: 5,
            label: "Go, Lang"
          }
        ],
        has_more: false
      };

      return {
        options: responseJSON.results,
        hasMore: responseJSON.has_more
      };
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>react-select-async-paginate</h1>
        <h2>1st Selectbox</h2>
        <select
          id="lang"
          onChange={this.firstSelectChange}
          value={this.state.firstSelectVal}
        >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="java">Java</option>
        </select>
        {this.state.firstSelectVal ? (
          <>
            <h2>2nd Selectbox</h2>
            <AsyncPaginate
              value={this.state.value}
              loadOptions={(search, prevOptions) =>
                this.loadHostOptions(search, prevOptions)
              }
              onChange={(e) => this.onPagiChange(e)}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your `onPagiChange` function to

```
onPagiChange = (event) => {
   this.setState({ value: event});
};
```

That is set the entire `event` as value instead of `event.value`

**Update**

The actual issue is whenever you click on the `AsyncPaginate` field it will call `loadHostOptions` function and pass the current value to the `search` argument. In that case whatever you type in will be the value of `search`.
So if you want to use the value of first Select box to filter option for the second one, you will have to directly use the `this.state.firstSelectVal` directly inside the `loadHostOptions` function. Like this

```
  loadHostOptions = async (search, prevOptions) => {
    if (this.state.firstSelectVal === "java") {
      const responseJSON = {
        results: [
          {
            value: 1,
            label: "Java"
          }
        ],
        has_more: false
      };

      return {
        options: responseJSON.results,
        hasMore: responseJSON.has_more
      };
    } else {
      const responseJSON = {
        results: [
          {
            value: 1,
            label: "Java"
          },
          {
            value: 2,
            label: "C++"
          },
          {
            value: 3,
            label: "Python"
          },
          {
            value: 4,
            label: "Node"
          },
          {
            value: 5,
            label: "Go Lang"
          }
        ],
        has_more: false
      };

      return {
        options: responseJSON.results,
        hasMore: responseJSON.has_more
      };
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it not the correct solution. Actually it's not about the selection of value in 2nd dropdown but it's about how to show correct lists in 2nd dropdown after selection of 1st dropdown value

Comment: Sorry there, didn't read the full stuff. I have updated the answer again. It should work now